# Java/Hector cassandra-client different performance on different OS

Tags: java, ubuntu, cassandra, thrift, hector

we are using `Cassandra` on 5 nodes replication 3 for over a year now.

Current Version 1.2.12

We wrote a program deleting records in `Cassandra` via `hector/Java`.

On the old OS (`OpenSuSE`) we had a write performance of about **2500 ops/sec**.
Now we are upgrading the nodes to `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. (`Cassandra` was not touched, has it own raid-system).
Due to that we move the Deleting-Programm to an other node with new OS.
On this node the write performance is about `70 ops/sec`, which is not acceptable.

We are using the same `JRE` and same Programm-Code on both machines.

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

are the same.

Profiling the java code on the slow machines say bottleneck is: `org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read()`

Does anywone know if there are any OS-setting wich slow down the cassandra operations?
Thanks for your help.

---

**Update: (day 3)**

- Noticed that on machines with `kernel 3.5` and lower the performance is OK ... keep searching
- machines with `kernel 3.8` have bad performance

---

**Update: (day 4)**

The "OS/kernel-suspicion" was wrong / now I have 2 ubuntu machines with same kernel Version / one is fast, one is slow

... no firewall ... checking network  :P

---

**Update: (day 5)**

I did some cross-test (connecting each node with each other by `AllOneConsistencyLevelPolicy`)
I've got more problems with cassandra-clients using `Kernel 3.8+` contacting Cassandra-servers `kernel <=3.5`.

- 3.8 to 3.8 some slow, some fast
- 3.8 to <3.5 some slow, some fast
- <3.5 to any other - always fast

I've no idea where to search next... brainstorming welcome ;)

---

Still slow... Just Connections to `localhost` are (always) fast. 
Having this phenomena on two different clusters in two different datacenters (also two different providers). So it's most likely it has nothing to do with the network infrastructure.

Cassandras has also different Versions in the second datacenter (2.0.6)

So I still think it's some Kernel-Issue ... no one else with this problem?

---

Found it ... we are running cassandra as a non-root-user. 
There is an extra "switch" in ubuntu which limits the number of open files.
It was following thread.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

Cite: 
[...]

You also need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` and add the following line to the end:

`session required pam_limits.so`

[...]

did the trick.

Comment: Check file-system on both OS. Maybe they are different.

Comment: FileSystems are the same. cassandra is on a separate raidvolume, which wasn't changed by new OS installation. When I run Programm on node 1 (old OS) it has high performance, on node 2 (new OS) it has poor performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your resource limits and raid configuration are the same on both.  Readahead is a particularly commonly misconfigured setting; see "setra" on this page: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html

*Special for **Ubuntu** with Cassandra running as **non-root** user:*

You also need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` and add the following line to the end:

`session required pam_limits.so`

cp. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

Comment: Thank you. That's a good check list for setting up cassandra. I checked the settings and all even the RAID-SA all looked ok. Well maybe my question was not exact enought. The problem seems not to be the cluster, but the Java-Client (Hector) which performs poor on ubuntu. I'll improve my question to this issue.